# Opencv disparity map: confusing units of measure

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, measurement, stereoscopy

I was reading the docs at: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html and got to the equation:

```
disparity=x−x′=Bf/Z
```

x  and x′ are the distance between points in image plane corresponding to the scene point 3D and their camera center. B is the distance between two cameras (which we know) and f is the focal length of camera (already known). Z is the distance of the point.

We have that B, f and z must all be meters because they represent a distance in the real world. Meanwhile the disparity is in pixels because it represents a distance of pixels in the image.

So the equation for the unit of measure is:

```
[pixel] = [m] * [m] / [m] = [m]
```

but a pixel is not equal to 1 meter! How can I make sense of the units of measure in order to apply this formula to a real world problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Camera calibration, focal length value seems too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69159247/camera-calibration-focal-length-value-seems-too-large)

Comment: f is in **pixels**, so you have disparity[px] = x[px] - x'[px] = B[m] * f[px] / Z[m]. -- f contains [m/m] or rather the tangent of an angle. it's unitless in that regard.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks a lot, the question you linked is in fact very interesting and useful for resolving my doubt.